# Customizing DatePicker with fxml

Tags: date, javafx, datepicker, initialization, customizing

I've added DatePicker with the help of Scene Builder into my fxml page.
How can I customize its date and also set current date at initial?

```
VBox vBox = (VBox) loader.load();
rootLayout.setRight(vBox);
DatePicker checkInDatePicker = new DatePicker(LocalDate.of(1998, 10, 8));
checkInDatePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the date inside the [`initialize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html#initialize-java.net.URL-java.util.ResourceBundle-) of the controller.

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML 
    DatePicker checkInDatePicker;

    ...

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        checkInDatePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
    }
}
```